# SQL INSERT INTO statement - how to insert space when field is an empty string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert-update

I have an INSERT INTO statement that I need to check if one of the field values I'm inserting is an empty string or not.  If it is, I need to insert an actual SPACE instead of an empty string.

```
INSERT INTO Vendors (LegacyID, ExternalID1, ExternalID2, EIN, LegalName, DBAName, ...)
```

How would I determine if EIN is an empty string here ('') and if so, actually insert a space (' ')?

The same for an UPDATE statement

```
Update Vendors SET LegacyID = ds.LegacyID, ExternalID1 = ds.ExtID1, ExternalID2 = ds.ExtID2, ...)
```

Any help and examples would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: you have a insert select ?   and /or a join update ? you should show all the code

Comment: Is this a case where you should be looking at a _constraint_ or _trigger_ to ensure that the column is never an empty string?

Comment: This sounds like some whacko idea that several years from now..somebody is going to go "why did somebody do this?".................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include the `VALUES` portion of the `INSERT`, nor the `EIN` in your `UPDATE`, so you've omitted the sections where you'd actually be making changes.

Because of this, I could only take a best-guess shot at what your actual fields may be, but the general jist of the answer is to use a `CASE` statement around the value going to be inserted.

**Example:**

```
-- If field is '', then use ' '.
-- Otherwise, use it as-is.
CASE field WHEN '' THEN ' ' ELSE field END
```

**Potential use-case (field names assumed):**

```
INSERT INTO Vendors (EIN, ds.LegacyID, ...) VALUES (CASE ds.EIN WHEN '' THEN ' ' ELSE ds.EIN END, ds.LegacyID, ...)
```

```
UPDATE Vendors SET EIN = CASE ds.EIN WHEN '' THEN ' ' ELSE ds.EIN END
```

Comment: The CASE statement worked great! Thank you very much.  I apologize for omitting the VALUES portion of my INSERT statement, but was looking how to use a IF or CASE statement in the INSERT INTO query - which is exactly what you provided.  Thank you again for your prompt reply.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [IIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on all the values.

I am not sure which are the varchar values so I am going to take a guess. Also I have no idea how you are getting your values so I will assume hard coded for now.

```
INSERT INTO Vendors (LegacyID, ExternalID1, ExternalID2, EIN, LegalName, DBAName, ...) 
VALUES (LegacyID, ExternalID1, ExternalID2, EIN, IIF(LegalName = '', ' ', LegalName), IIF(DBAName = '', ' ', DBAName), ...)

-- or

Update Vendors SET LegacyID = ds.LegacyID
    , ExternalID1 = ds.ExtID1
    , ExternalID2 = ds.ExtID2
    , LegalName = IIF(ds.LegalName = '', ' ', ds.LegalName)
    , DBAName = IIF(ds.DBAName = '', ' ', ds.LegalName)
    ...
```

---

Also I hope you have a valid reason/business case for doing this. If you really want an empty value the best thing to use is an empty string and for no value use `null`. Persisting a space only seems like an odd requirement, probably something that is probably only needed in the presentation layer but should probably not make it down into the persistence store.

Comment: Thank you!  I am very familiar with the IIF statement, but wasn't aware that was possible in T-SQL.  I ended up using a CASE statement, but will also give this a try.  The reason I need a space in a field is that the application reading the values from this table will crash if it sees a NULL or EMPTY STRING.  It's ridiculous and I completely agree it should be a NULL.  We've contacted the vendor in hopes they eventually correct it.  Furthermore I needed to do all this in a SQL query statement and not in a stored procedure.  Thank you again for your reply!

Comment: @DataCrypt - I am glad you found something that works. If you found the answer useful you can also upvote it using the up arrow as well as any other answers you found useful (its not limited to just 1 like the answer checkmark is).